# Difference $1 and $& Perl if only one capture group was found

Tags: regular-expression, perl

From my understanding, `$&` is the last found capture group. If there is only one capture group, why don't return both variables the same? E.g.:

```bsh
$ echo "key: value" | perl -ne "s/([a-z]+)(?=:)/\"$1\"/; print;" 
"": value
$ echo "key: value" | perl -ne "s/([a-z]+)(?=:)/\"$&\"/; print;"
"key": value
```

Comment: Hint: do you know what shells do with double-quoted `$1`?

Comment: Also, `$&` in Perl is similar to `&` in sed, i.e. it contains the whole matched string, regardless of any capture groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`perl`'s special variables are documented in `perldoc perlvar`.

If your pager is `less`, you can reach the section about `$&`, by searching for `^\s*\$&` (`$&` at the beginning of the line).

Or just use `perldoc -v '$&'` to extract the specific section about the `$&` variable:

> ```
> $&      The string matched by the last successful pattern match (not
>         counting any matches hidden within a BLOCK or "eval()" enclosed
>         by the current BLOCK).
>
>         See "Performance issues" above for the serious performance
>         implications of using this variable (even once) in your code.
>
>         This variable is read-only and dynamically-scoped.
>
>         Mnemonic: like "&" in some editors.
> ```

So it doesn't contain what is captured by any capture group but what is matched by the whole regexp.

In any case, your problem here is that `$1` is *expanded by the shell* to its first positional parameter (which looks like it's not set in your case) while `$&` is left alone as `$&` is not a valid variable name in your shell.

You'd want to use single quotes inside which `$` loses its special meaning in the shell:

```
echo 'key: value' | perl -pe 's/([a-z]+):/"$1":/'
```

```
echo 'key: value' | perl -pe 's/[a-z]+(?=:)/"$&"/'
```

More generally, you almost always want to use single (*strong*) quotes around code arguments of `perl` or any other language interpreter (`sed -e`, `awk`, `python -c`, `sh -c`...), not only because those languages often involve characters that happen to also be special for the shell, but also because, if as a result of not doing so, shell expansions are performed in there (like your `$1` expanded to the contents of the first position parameter here), that can quickly become a code injection vulnerability (think of what would have happened if `$1` had contained `/;system "reboot" #` for instance here).

Comment: Awesome! You did not only answer my question, but also added some great general advice to it :)

Comment: `perldoc -Tv '$&'`

Comment: Thanks @user414777! I wasn't aware of that one. I've included it now.